# Adding multiple elements to a single line of a List

Tags: c#, list, monogame

Hi I am trying to add sets of coordinates to a single line of a List (so x, y as a single list line). I am currently generating the x and y coordinates as I break up an image and display the chunks in a grid. I am hitting a brick wall in being able to add both x and y to the same List line. Here is the code I have so far -

```
    float sf = 1f;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int width = tileImage.Width / tileNumber;
    int height = tileImage.Height / tileNumber;
    int placeXValue = (width / 10);
    int placeYValue = (height / 10);
    int placeX = placeXValue;
    int placeY = placeYValue;
    Rectangle tileRect = tileImage.Bounds;
    tileRect.Width = width;
    tileRect.Height = height;
    coordinates = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < tileNumber; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < tileNumber; j++)
        {
            tileRect.X = x;
            tileRect.Y = y;
            _spriteBatch.Draw(tileImage, new Vector2((x + placeX) * sf, (y + placeY) * sf), tileRect, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(0, 0), sf, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
            placeX += placeXValue;
            x += width;
            coordinates.Add(x,y);
        }
        x = 0;
        y += height;
        placeX = placeXValue;
        placeY += placeYValue;
    }
```

Comment: You probably need something like `coordinates.Add(new Coordinate(x, y))`, but without knowing what your coordinates list is we can't tell. Please [edit] your question to include the declaration of the coordinates list. The main problem is that you are trying to give 2 parameters to a method that only accepts 1

Comment: use coordinates = new List<Point>();

Comment: Added an answer for how I solved the issue I was having

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do what I was trying to in the question. The first thing that I did was change my - `private List<int> coordinates;` - to a tuple list like this - `List<Tuple<int, int>> coordinates;` - This then allowed me to add my x and y elements to a new list by using the - `coordinates.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(x,y));` - tuple functionality. Making this change has allowed me to add my generated coordinate pairs to my list.